# using href attribute as parameter in grep

Tags: jquery, json, attributes

Im trying to use the href attribute of a link to filter a json array with grep.

The grep works fine when the href value is hard coded into the grep parameter, (ie, el.category_name.toLowerCase() === "y"), but it doesnt work when I try to add the href dynamically as a variable from the button's href arrtibute.

I think it might be a question of scope... but Im not sure how to set up the variable.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is what I've been trying --

```
$('#category_name').click(function()
  {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.getJSON('data/all.json',
      function(data)
      { 
        location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)
         { 
          return 'el.' + href + '.toLowerCase() === "y"'
         });

      //returned grep-ed objects mapped to html//

     });
   });
```

Comment: is href being populated property?   put an alert right before : return 'el.' + href + '.toLowerCase() === "y"'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#category_name').click(function()
  {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.getJSON('data/all.json',
      function(data)
      { 
        location = $.grep(data, function(el, i)
         { 
          return el[href].toLowerCase() === "y"'
         });

      //returned grep-ed objects mapped to html//

     });
   });
```

Comment: Im getting [el]href is undefined. Tried a few different variations on data.el + [href] etc and no luck.

Comment: You can always try return $('#category_name').attr('href') == "y"